# Cliente - Servidor erro consola

Tags: java

Tenho um cliente e servidor a funcionar para enviar mensagens a partir de uma aplicação Chat porem da me um erro na consola quando tento escrever uma mensagem. Alguém me sabe explicar o erro?

Erro na consola

```
Cliente ligou-se ao servidor
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at janela.PainelMensagens.escreverMensagem(PainelMensagens.java:73)
at janela.PainelMensagens$ButtonActionListener.keyPressed(PainelMensagens.java:106)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6493)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2832)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6312)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4762)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

---

```
public class PainelMensagens extends JPanel{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private EstadoMensagem estadoMensagem = null;
private JButton botaoEnviar;
private JTextField zonaEscreverMensagens;
private JTextArea zonaReceberMensagens;
private JanelaUtilizador janelaUtilizador;

private ButtonActionListener buttonListener;

public PainelMensagens(JanelaUtilizador janelaUtilizador) {
    this.janelaUtilizador = janelaUtilizador;

    buttonListener = new ButtonActionListener();

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    criarPainelEscrita();
    criarPainelLeitura();
}


private void criarPainelEscrita(){
    JPanel painelEscrita = new JPanel();
    painelEscrita.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    zonaEscreverMensagens = new JTextField();
    zonaEscreverMensagens.addKeyListener(buttonListener);

    botaoEnviar = new JButton("Enviar");
    botaoEnviar.addActionListener(buttonListener);

    painelEscrita.add(zonaEscreverMensagens, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    painelEscrita.add(botaoEnviar, BorderLayout.EAST);

    add(painelEscrita, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

private void criarPainelLeitura(){
    zonaReceberMensagens = new JTextArea();
    zonaReceberMensagens.setEditable(false);

    add(zonaReceberMensagens, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}


public void escreverMensagem(){
    estadoMensagem = EstadoMensagem.ENVIADA;

    String mensagemEnviada = "Eu: " + zonaEscreverMensagens.getText();
    zonaReceberMensagens.setText(zonaReceberMensagens.getText() + mensagemEnviada + "   " + estadoMensagem.getEstado() + "\n");
    zonaEscreverMensagens.setText("");                  //depois de escrever uma mensagem a zona de escrever mensagens passa a estar limpa

    Contacto contacto = janelaUtilizador.getPainelContactos().getListaContactos().getSelectedValue();

    Mensagem mensagem = new Mensagem(contacto, mensagemEnviada);

    contacto.getMensagens().add(mensagem);

}

public EstadoMensagem getEstadoMensagem() {
    return estadoMensagem;
}

public JTextField getZonaEscreverMensagens() {
    return zonaEscreverMensagens;
}

public JTextArea getZonaReceberMensagens() {
    return zonaReceberMensagens;
}


class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        escreverMensagem();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            escreverMensagem();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Adicione sua classe PainelMensagens na pergunta também, o erro está sendo disparado dela.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe já adicionei

Comment: Onde é a linha 73? `estadoMensagem` está `NULL` e você está tentando fazer um `.getEstado()` em uma variavel nula. Cheque a terceira linha do seu método `escreverMensagem()`.

Answer (score 1):

Esta dando NullPointerException, você está utilizando o evento keypressed então no momento que você clica dentro do inputText ele já irá submeter o valor. Verifique se esse objeto "zonaReceberMensagens" está vindo diferente de null debugando o código, pois a cada tecla informada no JTextField e feita uma chamada do método.